# Bridging Ethernet Adapters for Active Backup?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, network-adapter, windows-server-2012

I have two ethernet adapters I have bridged. I would like to configure them for active backup in case one of them should fail. How do I do this?

Comment: Which Windows version are you using, exactly? Why are the adapters bridged? Are they connected to a switch that supports LACP?

Comment: Well, it is a virtual machine of Windows server 2012 r2. I was messing around with network bridging and like the idea of active backup. Where if one port dies, the other takes over.